# Adding multiple image layers in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I am working on an app that creates different types of ID cards. User will take a picture and input data and the app will make the ID for them. I would like the app to give you option to either save the final ID picture or share it online, so I need the result to be put together into a single image file. I have some ID templates, but I am having trouble adding multiple layers on top of it, like the picture, and some text (name, DOB etc..)

I tried simply using ImageViews with relative layout but I cant get the picture to line up perfectly on top of the template, I tried LayerDrawable, I tried SurfaceView, I tried different things and I am desperate for an answer.

What is the best approach to layer the user's picture on top of a template, along with some text?

Comment: post image or your xml file to get your question easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a canvas to draw on a Bitmap.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
```

Just be sure the .createBitmap() you use creates a mutable bitmap. Then you get the canvas from that and use that to draw the image on the bitmap. You can do very fine grain controls and you have it in one block of memory, etc.